# how to store session data in couchapp

Tags: jquery, session, couchdb, couchapp

to query parameters for eventlies and show-functions?
to store global language options for example?

Comment: Why did you tag this with `jQuery`? Seems like this question is entirely about CouchDB storage.

Comment: Because CouchApps use a lot of jquery and -extensions. The global application ($.app)-objects and their events are beeing stored with jquery. I hoped there are jquery-extensions for session handling, too.

Comment: jQuery is a client library. Session data is stored on the server between requests. Ergo, jQuery is irrelevant here. ;)

Comment: jQuery is relevant if the questioner says it's relevant.  The tag is an indication that he is using jQuery, and that he would be receptive to a solution that uses jQuery. -- so lighten up, guys.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the HTML5 API for local storage or session storage, thus maintaining session state on the client side. You'd have to construct the requests on the client, though, passing the session data with each request.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute

Answer (score 0):

For one thing the couchDB jQuery library got a session method alowing you to get common session data: http://daleharvey.github.com/jquery.couch.js-docs/symbols/%24.couch.html#.session

I haven't tried yet to store anything else in a session since I didn't need to. You could still use plain old JavaScript to set a cookie containing all your additional session data. ( http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html )

cu
Roman